# Python while loop, coin toss 3 times

Tags: python

I am trying to create a coin toss three times using while loop, but
   there are various issues here and iam not professional yet.

My code didn't run the way i wanted it to run it's only a test code
   for now...here are the issues:

- it is not looping for some reason, runs only once.
- it's only printing tails, never print heads.
- i have to place the else
  statement in the beginning of the line every time in order for the
  program to run without giving me an invalid syntax message...why??
- how do i make it loop 3 times exactly?

ANY help will be appreciated. Code is below

```
import random

heads_counter=0 tails_counter=0

while heads_counter and tail_counter <= 3:
    a= random.randint (1,2)
    if a==1:
        print ("heads",heads_counter)
        heads_counter+=1

else:
    print ("tails",tails_counter)
    tails_counter+=1
```

Comment: Do you want to check the edit represent your *actual* code? Looked like the edit introducing `>`s at the start of the code block was to try and put indentation back in for your if/else, but not 100% sure...

Comment: @JonClements The `else` being indented inline with the `while` would explain why it always seemed to choose tails. (That's how it appeared when I first edited the question.)

Comment: @chepner yep... looking more closely at the OPs edit, it didn't introduce indentation... so I've rolled back to yours (again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem here is:

```
while heads_counter and tail_counter <= 3:
```

I am assuming you'd like something more along the lines of this:

```
while heads_counter + tail_counter <= 3:
    a= random.randint (1,2)
    if a==1:
        print ("heads",heads_counter)
        heads_counter+=1

    else:
        print ("tails",tails_counter)
        tails_counter+=1

print ("heads total",heads_counter)
print ("tails total",tails_counter)
```

Remember: Indentation is important in Python.

While loop specification: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more explicit in the `while` condition:

```
while heads_counter <=3 and tail_counter <= 3:
```

Your code is always false, because `head_counter`, initialized to 0, is false. That is enough to make the entire `and`'d condition false.

(Update: as kachingy123 pointed out, you actually want to compare the *sum* of the two variables to 3. Python is more precise than English, which can use "and" as a synonym
for "plus".

```
while head_counter + tail_counter <= 3:
```

)

You also need to indent the `else` clause to match the `if`, since a `while` loop can *also* take an `else` clause (which is executed when the loop exits due to its condition being false, rather than an explicit break).

Finally, you need put your two variable assignments on separate lines. (You *could* just separate them with a semi-colon, but that isn't considered good practice.)

```
import random

heads_counter=0
tails_counter=0

# With update from kachingy123
while heads_counter + tail_counter <= 3:
    a = random.randint (1,2)
    if a==1:
        heads_counter += 1
        print ("heads",heads_counter) 
    else:
        tails_counter += 1
        print ("tails",tails_counter)
```

Comment: I think the intention from the original text stipulates only three coin flips: "I am trying to create a coin toss three times using while loop"

Comment: thank for replying , though iam trying to have the program prints only 3 tosses and then the total but now it is including 0 in the count, here is the output iam trying to get::...   Tossing.....  tail    (  2  ) 
Tossing.....  tail    (  2  ) 
Tossing.....  head    (  1  ) 
1 heads and  2 tails
Winner: Tails

Comment: @aero You need to update the counters before printing their values; I'll make that change.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'while' clause is incorrect.  The statement

```
while a and b <= c
```

is not evaluated as

```
while (a and b) <= c
```

it evaluates to:

```
while (a) and (b <= c)
```

In this case, a is your heads_counter variable, which is initialized to 0, hence it evaluates to false and your loop never runs

Also, as noted by khelwood, your indentation levels are incorrect.  Your `else` clause needs to be indented at the same level as the corresponding `if` clause

Comment: so you're saying i need three vars instead of just the a ?

Comment: Even `(a and b) <= c` would be wrong if it were parsed that way.

Comment: No, in the example a, b, c are just placeholders for whatever you use in your conditional.  I was just trying to illustrate how it evaluates the statement.  In your case `a` is `heads_counter`, `b` is `tails_counter`, and `c` is the constant you were attempting to check them against

Answer (score 1):

A note on style:

Python has a remarkable verbosity that few other languages match. Use it! Don't do `while a + b < 3`, do `for coinflip in range(3)`. Don't do `result = random.randint(1,2)` then parse `random` into heads or tails, do `result = random.choice("heads","tails")`. Heck, run it all at once in one big list and sort it later!

My recommendations:

```
import random
results = {'heads':0, 'tails':0}
for coinflip in range(3):
    results[random.choice('heads','tails')] += 1
```

which is more simply

```
import random
results = dict()
for coinflip in range(3):
    results.setdefault(random.choice('heads','tails'), 0) += 1
```

or even more simply:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

Counter(random.choice('heads','tails') for flip in range(3))
```

Comment: @chepner agreed, but it's a bit too long for a comment. Plus, code formatting and etc. The OP got plenty of duplicate responses to the issues with the code he wrote. I'm loathe to write another.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an indentation problem. If your `else` clause corresponds to your `if`, then it should be at the same indentation level as it.

Also your while condition needs to check `heads_counter <=3 and tail_counter <= 3` and your initialisation for your counter variables should be separated, as chepner pointed out.

```
heads_counter = 0
tails_counter = 0

while heads_counter <= 3 and tail_counter <= 3:
    a= random.randint (1,2)
    if a==1:
        print ("heads",heads_counter)
        heads_counter+=1
    else:
        print ("tails",tails_counter)
        tails_counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

All Credit to [@kachingy123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651309/kachingy123) for the original solution to this, however, I noticed the print statements printed before the counter incremented. I just swapped the statements:

```
# Coin Toss Machine
import random

heads_counter = 0
tails_counter = 0

while heads_counter + tails_counter <= 3:
    a= random.randint (1,2)
    if a==1:
        heads_counter+=1
        print ("heads",heads_counter)

    else:
        tails_counter+=1
        print ("tails",tails_counter)

print ("heads total",heads_counter)
print ("tails total",tails_counter)
```